# Is the t-test on Sci-py stats Welch's t-test

Tags: scipy, statistics

I am trying to determine if the default t-test in sci-py is Welch's t-test or the student's t-test.  I can't find an answer anywhere.  I used the following code to do my t-test analysis.  If it is not Welch's, can anyone advise me how to do Welch's

```
t_test = scipy.stats.ttest_ind(a, b, axis=0)
```

Thanks
Emma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between those two tests is the assumption regarding equal variances. Welch's test does not assume equal variances. If you pass `equal_var=False` to your t-test (`scipy.stats.ttest_ind(a, b, equal_var=False, axis=0)` it will conduct Welch's test.

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html):

> equal_var : bool, optional If True (default), perform a standard
>   independent 2 sample test that assumes equal population variances.
>   If False, perform Welch’s t-test, which does not assume equal
>   population variance.

Comment: Thanks heaps for that!